# Debugging __NSAutoreleaseFreedObject():

Tags: xcode, cocoa

is there anyway to add a breakpoint for the following warning:

*** __NSAutoreleaseFreedObject(): release of previously deallocated object (0x1003e1720) ignored

I've tried adding an exception breakpoint on objective c exceptions without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__NSAutoreleaseFreedObject` symbol is for the `_NSAutoreleaseFreedObject` function (single underscore). The underscore means it's private (certainly a static function).

So you won't be able to place a breakpoint, as the function is not exported.

You may try to define's the function's prototype in some of your header file:

```
void __NSAutoreleaseFreedObject( void * o );
```

The, you should be able to set a breakpoint from GDB:

```
break __NSAutoreleaseFreedObject
```

Answer (score 0):

try a symbolic breakpoint for that symbol